# A select form alternative with list

Tags: forms, select, html-lists

neHello, I would like to make 3 selectable item in my advanced serach but I want use `<select>` and `<option>`.
I would like to use <`ul><li>` and a `<a href="">SEND</a>` like a button submit.

Do you know some tutorial or website where explain this?
I would prefer to use jquery.

After the submit, I want go to the page

`avanced_search.php?label_1=&&label_2=paris&&label_3=S`

I have this :

```
<ul id="label_1">
    <li title="">All</li>
    <li title="Belgique">Belgique</li>
    <li title="France">France</li>
    <li title="Espagne">Espagne</li>
    <li title="USA">USA</li>
</ul>
<ul id="label_2">
    <li title="">All</li>
    <li title="Gantt">Gantt</li>
    <li title="Bruges">Bruges</li>
    <li title="Paris">Paris</li>
    <li title="Marseille">Marseille</li>
    <li title="Madrid">Madrid</li>
    <li title="Barcelone">Barelone</li>
    <li title="NY">NY</li>
    <li title="LA">LA</li>
</ul>
<ul id="label_3">
    <li title="">All</li>
    <li title="N">Nord</li>
    <li title="E">Est</li>
    <li title="S">Sud</li>
    <li title="O">OUEST</li>
</ul>
<a id="send_all">SEND</a>
```

It's not required to select an option. (default is nothing)

For design, I would to have "All" selected, when I clik on, the list appear and when I click on Paris (for example) I have Paris selected and "All" unselected .

More but not required, if it's possible, when I choose USA in the label 1 Can I have just LA and NY?

Thanks for your help!